# How can I simplify $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\right|}\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\right|}\cdot
> \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I'd like to know how can I simplify that correctly?

Here is what I did:

$$\frac{x}{\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\right|\right)}\cdot
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{x^2}{\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-1\right|\right)\cdot
\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Is that it or can you go further and make it look more nice / simple?

Comment: What if x is negative. Your first step is itself wrong.

Comment: Try to multiply $\sqrt{x^2+1}+1$ for both the denominator and numerator.

Comment: Ya it doesnt matter as it again becomes x^2 but its good to use mod sign

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, it *does* matter (so your first comment is both correct and pertinent).  $\sqrt{x^2}x$ is negative when $x$ is negative, but $x^2$ is never negative, so the simplified form should be $|x|x$.

Comment: Oh yes completely forgot it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since $$\sqrt{x^2+1}\geq 1$$we get
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1)}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
note that $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=\frac{|x|}{x}$$ and $$x\ne 0$$
ps.: $$\frac{|x|}{x}=1$$ if $$x>0$$ and $-1$ if $$x<0$$

Comment: no it isn't we have $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$